# Google Appengine Admin API apps.services.versions.patch - INVALID_ARGUMENT

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

When I send a PATCH request to the method: `apps.services.versions.patch` I got an error response:

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "At least one field must be specified for this operation.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
}
```

I have used `Try this API` tools for testing.

My CURL

```
curl --request PATCH \
  'https://appengine.googleapis.com/v1/apps/{APP_ID}/services/{SERVICE_ID}/versions/{VERSION}' \
  --header 'Authorization: Bearer [YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN]' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' \
  --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --data '{"envVariables":{"TEST_PARAM":"test_value"},"servingStatus":"STOPPED"}' \
  --compressed
```

This API doesn't have any required arguments. https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch

Comment: You forgot to include the query parameter "updateMask" which tells the API what to update (PATCH).

Answer (score 0):

Like *@JohnHanley* mentioned, you need to add the [updateMask](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps.services.versions/patch?apix_params=%7B%22appsId%22%3A%22test-project-2108%22%2C%22servicesId%22%3A%22finance%22%2C%22versionsId%22%3A%2220201022t142537%22%2C%22resource%22%3A%7B%7D%7D#query-parameters) parameter that will specify which fields should be updated.